# Recode for loop (recursion) using Rcpp

Tags: r, for-loop, rcpp

I have to calculate a for loop several 100.000 times with R and want to optimize that with Rcpp (or alternatives):

```
for (t in 1:num) {
      Xt<- c(t(yt[.N:(.N-h)]))      
      yt<- rbindlist(list(yt, as.list(Xt %*% coeff)))
 }
```

```
Xt %*% coeff
```

is a Matrix Multiplication.

After struggling a lot with Rcpp ... Are there any hints how to recode that using Rcpp? Is it easily possible, because the calculation of Xt is not trivial to me.

I also implemented a R recursion function, which is not really faster than this loop.

Thank you

Comment: Have you profiled your R code? It is quite likely that the majority of time is spent on matrix multiplication. That is done by BLAS library in compiled code, so you won’t gain anything from going to C++.

Comment: The Matrix multiplication is quite fast, because in my case the Matrix is quite small (< 100 x 100). Most time will spend for the Manipulation to calculate Xt

Comment: Ok. How about providing a [mre] together with your profiling results?

Comment: Also (maybe this is just me being thick and missing something), I do not see anything happening in the loop. You have `for (t in 1:num)`, but you never use `t` (though you do use the function `t()`?)

Comment: t() is to transpose and the index t will not be used. But as you might notice the Matrix yt will be updated in each step by a new row and then used in the next step to be updated again

Comment: BTW, a verbal or mathematical description of what you are trying to do might also help.

Comment: I see, you're just doing it `num` times, of course! Sorry, was just having a momentary lapse I guess. I think @RalfStubner is dead on here. Mathematical description is the way to go. You can often speed things up much more by thinking about the math than thinking about the code (helps you try math tricks first, helps you think about fastest code to match the math rather than little things to improve the approach you already have, etc.) (just my experience, YMMV)

Comment: I came back to see if there were any updates on this @Vit, and looking at it again, it seems very possible that you may have a lot of wasted time in unnecessary or inefficient data conversions. I think if you edit your question to provide a description of the mathematical technique you're trying to implement, you could probably get an answer that would help your optimization considerably.